# Horizontal spacing for NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, kerning

I'm trying to display an image in a `UITextField` using `NSTextAttachment`, but I want some horizontal space between the image and the text. However, when add the `NSKernAttributeName` attribute to the attributed string as follows, it resets the height of the attachment to the same height as the surrounding text.

```
var str = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment))
str.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 10, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: 1))
```

Is there another way to add horizontal space between the image and the text?

Comment: I am searching for the same? Any Luck till now?

Answer (score -1):

The most direct way is in string start set a few space :

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
[attachment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dest_poi_content_quotation"]];
NSString *reviewText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", review.text];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:reviewText];
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
[attributedString insertAttributedString:attrStringWithImage atIndex:0];
[self.lblComment setAttributedText:attributedString];
```